# Php array object check children array for value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I have the following object:

```
[335] =  WP_Post Object 
  (
   [post_author] = 6
   [post_date] = 2018-03-12 14:33:06
   [page_id] = 333
   [wpse_children] = Array
       (
           [441] =  WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] = 441
                   [post_date] = 2018-03-16 20:47:14                 
                   [post_parent] = 333
                   [menu_item_parent] = 335
                   [page_id] = 385                
               )

           [441] =  WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] = 452
                   [post_date] = 2018-03-16 20:47:14                 
                   [post_parent] = 333
                   [menu_item_parent] = 335
                   [page_id] = 442                
               )

           [541] =  WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] = 480
                   [post_date] = 2018-03-16 20:47:14                 
                   [post_parent] = 333
                   [menu_item_parent] = 335
                   [page_id] = 680                
               )         

       )
)
```

I'm using the object to create a navigation menu in HTML with children menu items as a dropdown:

> - Parent menu item
>
>   - Submenu item 1
>   - Submenu item 2
>   - Submenu item 3

`$menu_item` is the main object.

I can get for example, the post author id value by using `$menu_item->post_author`.

For each menu item, I'm adding a class named `active` if it is on the current page:

```
if ($menu_item->page_id == $current_page_id) {
  array_push($class_names, 'current-menu-item');
}
```

(`$class_names` are later added to the menu item class attribute)

This works fine but I also want to keep the class `active` on the parent menu item if on a child item page.

How can I check the object's `wpse_children` array to see if `page_id` is equal to `$current_page_id` and `menu_item_parent` is equal to the main objcet id (in this case `335`)?

If true, i want to add class `active` to the parent item.

Comment: The `menu_item_parent` is right in the objects - what's the deal?

Comment: I don't know how to check for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$menu_item` is the object you described you can just iterate over `$menu_item->wpse_children`.

```php
foreach($menu_item->wpse_children as $child) {
    // do stuff with children
    if ($child->page_id === $current_page_id) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i tried but get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: Are you sure you did this in the right place? Is `$menu_item` really what you stated above? Can you `var_dump($menu_item)` and see what it is and if it has `wpse_children`?

Comment: I had to check first if objeect/array is not empty

Comment: Glad you figured it out.